# FixedUpdate() callback is not called on one instance of a script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that is attached to both an object and to a child object of that object.

The FixedUpdate() callback is called on the parent object but not on the child object.

Both objects are created in runtime and the script attached with addComponent<> and are active although the child object has been set to inactive at some point and then made active again.

Any thoughts?

[edit #1 images added as per comment]

the parent
[image: image of inspector for parent object]

the child
[image: image of inspector for child object]

Comment: can you please show some screenshots of the inspector or something

Comment: @Z3RP i'm not sure that helps us at, but inspector screenshots added.... shows both object active and scripts (Obstruction Scanner) active

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that on each fixedUpdate, some other process was setting the child object to inactive while running some test conditions. If the conditions were positive, then the child object would be activated again. However, it was being activated after the fixedUpdate call.